# React Native fetch a local server using a proxy

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, proxy, fetch-api

In my react native app I am trying to perform a `fetch` to my local backend server. In my `package.json` I have put `"proxy": "http://localhost:3000"`.

My fetch looks like:

```
fetch('/')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(json => console.log(json))
  .catch(err => console.log)
```

It catches an error

> [TypeError: Network request failed]

---

When I remove the proxy and manually enter the address in the fetch it works and my server receives a GET request.

```
fetch('http://localhost:3000')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(json => console.log(json))
  .catch(err => console.log)
```

Answer (score 5):

Two points here:

- Set `proxy` in `package.json` is [a feature of create-react-app](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development/), which wraps [webpack dev server's proxy](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserverproxy). react-native uses Metro instead of Webpack as bundler and it does not support setting up a local proxy.
- Different from the web, http client in react-native has no current `host`. So if you use `fetch('/')`, it won't know which domain or ip address to send request to.

Answer (score 0):

hello you can use your network IP Address for using local server like instead localhost change with your Ip address and you can call your server e.g, http://192.xxx.x.xxx:3000